# StreamWriter not writing to file in C# console

Tags: c#, filestream, streamwriter, writer

I'm new to programming and C# is the language I'm learning. My homework instructions are:

Create a program named  WritelnventoryRecords  that allows you to enter data for items you sell at an online auction site and saves the data to a file. Create an Inventory class that contains fields for item number, description, and asking price.

The code I've written will not write to the text file, it's just blank. What am I missing?

```
using System;
using System.IO;
class Inventory
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.Write("How many items would you like to enter? ");
        FileStream file = new FileStream("ItemsSold.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(file);
        int num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        int itemNum = 0;
        string desc;
        double price;

        for (int count = 0; count < num; ++count)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter an item number: ");
            itemNum = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Enter the item description: ");
            desc = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Enter the item price (no dollar sign): ");
            price = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            writer.WriteLine(itemNum + "," + desc + "," + price);
        }
        writer.Close();
        file.Close();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code already?

Comment: I don't think there's something wrong with the code, but I can suggest doing `new StreamWriter("ItemsSold.txt");` immediately without having to create a file stream as it would output the same result.

Comment: Are you sure you're looking in the right location for your text file? You should also ensure you dispose classes that implement `IDisposable` (`FileStream` and `StreamWriter`), the preferred way of doing this is with a `using` block: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx

Comment: I've copied your code exactly and it's working just fine.

Comment: Well this is embarrassing. I stepped away to eat dinner, ran it again when I came back )(no changes made) and it works just fine. The only thing I can think of is that I was opening the wrong file. but I don't know how when it was the only text file in the same location as the executable. I appreciate the input. Sorry I wasted your time.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works on my machine.
If it's still not works, you can try following steps:

1. When open the file stream, use "FileMode.OpenOrCreate" flag.
2. Reset the file using "file.SetLength(0);" just after create the file steam.
3. Flush the buffer before close the file stream: "writer.Flush();"

   === EDIT ===

And yes, like @Preston Guillot posted, check if you are opening the right file.

Comment: can use the following to get the full path to the file:  string filePath = Path.GetFullPath("ItemSold.txt"); Console.WriteLine("Saved to File: {0}", filePath);

Comment: FileMode.OpenOrCreate doesnt do what you think it will... FileMode.Create is the correct thing to be using in this situation as you are writing the file in one go. OpenOrCreate gets a stream to an existing file which you can use to write a section of the file.